# Не могу раскодировать тело письма Gmail POP3

Tags: python, gmail, pop3

```
import email
import poplib

login = "my_login"
password = "my_pass"
pop3_server = "pop.gmail.com"

gmail = poplib.POP3_SSL(pop3_server, "995")
gmail.set_debuglevel(1)
gmail.user(login)
gmail.pass_(password)
number_of_messages = len(gmail.list()[1])
print(number_of_messages)
lines = gmail.retr(number_of_messages)[1]
msg_content = b'\n\r'.join(lines)
message = email.message_from_bytes(msg_content)
print(message)
```

**Я ожидаю получить**

```
Delivered-To: ivankoivanivanov33@gmail.com

Received: by 2002:a05:6e04:583:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id r3csp1208903imz;

Wed, 20 Oct 2021 09:29:39 -0700 (PDT)

<html>
....
content of message
....
</html>
```

**Но получаю**

```
Delivered-To: ivankoivanivanov33@gmail.com

Received: by 2002:a05:6e04:583:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id r3csp1208903imz;

Wed, 20 Oct 2021 09:29:39 -0700 (PDT)

DQo8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbCBQVUJMSUMgIi0vL1czQy8vRFREIFhIVE1MIDEuMCBUcmFu

c2l0aW9uYWwvL0VOIiAiaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvVFIveGh0bWwxL0RURC94aHRt

bDEtdHJhbnNpdGlvbmFsLmR0ZCI+DQo8IS0tIFRoaXMgaXMgdGhlIG5ldyBlbWFpbCB0

ZW1wbGF0ZSBmb3IgU1NQUiB3aGljaCBhbGlnbnMgd2VsbCB3aXRoIHRoZSBlbWFpbCB0
```

Comment: HTML контент закодирован в base64

Comment: Приведенные заголовки - все? Больше никаких нет?

Answer (score 0):

Кодировки тела письма и соответствующие им заголовки описаны в [RFC 2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045). Конкретно это письмо закодировано Base64, что должно быть отражено в заголовках, иначе вам придётся применять в программе какую-то эвристику для её обнаружения.

Кроме упомянутого RFC для корректного разбора писем вам как минимум понадобятся [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322) и [RFC 2047](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047).

Comment: Где мне указать кодировку?

Answer (score 0):

```
import poplib
from email.parser import Parser

login = ""
password = ""
pop3_server = "pop.yandex.com"
server = poplib.POP3_SSL(pop3_server)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
pop3_server_welcome_msg = server.getwelcome().decode('utf-8')
server.user(login)
server.pass_(password)
print('Messages: %s. Size: %s' % server.stat())
resp, mails, octets = server.list()
print(mails)
index = len(mails)
lines = server.retr(index)[1]

msg_content = b'\r\n'.join(lines).decode('utf-8')
msg = Parser().parsestr(msg_content)
content = msg.get_payload(decode=True).decode("utf-8")
print(content)

server.quit()
```

**Этот код возвращает красивый HTML**

Всем спасибо за ответы!